# C# Remove drawing from PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox

I have a `PictureBox` pic , and an `Image` img, `pic.Image = img` 
and I draw some rectangles on the Image using

```
Graphics g = Grpahics.FromImage(pic.Image);
g.DrawRectangle(...);
```

But at one point, I want to remove the rectangle from the Image,I tried

```
pic.Image = getOriginalImage();
pic.Refresh();
```

but the image remains the same(Rectangles are still on top of the Image)
I know there's a method `graphics.Clear(Color)`,but it replace the entire Image with a solid color
How do I remove the drawing only from the `PictureBox`?
Thanks

Edit:
I already saved the original and when I erase I use the original image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overwriting the original image. Save the image locally and clone it into the PictureBox.Image property. Then clone again when you want to erase

Comment: Thanks, but I already saved the original image and use it when erase, see my edit question

Comment: Oh, Actually you are right, I did save the original Image but I didn't use `Clone`, I assign the Image directly to the `PictureBox`

Answer (score 2):

Draw the background image again using [Graphics.DrawImage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx) or assign the image again to the Image property. Using a `Graphics` object in this way is writing directly to the image displayed in the `PictureBox` and it does not keep separate copies of what is written using a Graphics object and the background Image.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using `Graphics.DrawImage()`